# Can I set a RecyclerView to have buttons with gradual changing colours as it goes down the list?

Tags: java, android

I'm looking to make a `RecyclerView` with a `CardView`, where each `CardView` is a solid colour (starting at dark red) and then as the list goes on, each `CardView` gets lighter and lighter (ending at a light red/pinkish colour). The list size is unknown, and if only one cell is present, it would just be the dark red. I only have the starting colour and end colour.

I know how to set each individual button to a specific colour only:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(DetailsRecyclerAdapter.viewHolder holder, int position) { 

        if (position == 0) {
 viewHolder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.darkRed));
        }

        if (position == (list.size()-1)) {
viewHolder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.lightRed));
        }
    }
```

A kind commenter has asked me to add the values of the colours:

```
    <color name="darkRed">#F48B5E</color>
    <color name="lightRed">#E9A191</color>
```

This only sets the first and last cells to the colours I need, is there any way I can go about having a gradient going through the middle? Thanks everybody in advance!

Comment: Could you please add the values of `R.color.darkRed` and `R.color.lightRed` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [ArgbEvaluator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ArgbEvaluator) to get a gradual color passing the starting color, ending color and the position to calculate the fraction.

Add the following method to your Adapter class and use it to get the background-color

```java
// Custom method to generate gradual color

protected int getColorCode(int position){

    int startColor = Color.parseColor("#F48B5E");
    int endColor = Color.parseColor("#E9A191");

    float fraction = position / (float)getItemCount();
    int color = (Integer) new ArgbEvaluator().evaluate(fraction, startColor, endColor);
    return color;
}
```

```java
public void onBindViewHolder(DetailsRecyclerAdapter.viewHolder holder, int position) {

   // use the above method to set the color
   viewHolder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(getColorCode(position));
}
```

[image]

Comment: this is pretty awesome !